# Basement walls in bad repair?

Tags: walls, foundation, water-damage, cement

We recently bought an older home built in the late 30’s. Previous owner painted the basement cement walls.. bad move. They look like this.
Attached is a wall where the other side is the exterior of the foundation below grade.
[image]
Hairline cracks and a slight yellow tinge in less than .05% .. very insignificant discoloration.. but my worry is that is all that’s showing up because of the paint. Does this look like Drylok? Parts can be chipped off.. not sure if areas are spalling. Advice?

Update: our basement is very dry. Around 18% humidity (in the winter) not sure what the previous owners plans were with the plywood. Maybe wanted to cover the piping. Does this look like water intrusion or just superficial cracking?
[image]

Comment: The photo looks like it could be upside down. Is that plywood applied to the wall? More pictures from various distances would be great.

Comment: Please point out the hairline crack(s). All I see is a “mud line” where one load was dropped upon a load already in the form.

Comment: Your basement is "very dry" and runs about 18% humidity in the winter? What, exactly, is it you're worried about? There are people who would _kill_ to have a basement that dry. If you don't see moisture on the walls or puddling on the floor, I don't think you've got _anything_ to worry about at all. Not sure where you (or @LeeSam) were seeing any plywood. Looks like someone started some 2x4 framing to put an interior wall up to hide the plumbing/electrical work, but never finished the job.

Comment: For a home that's nearly 100 years old, that wall looks to be in excellent condition.

Answer (score 0):

If you have moisture issues it is best to fix from the outside.  What is the relative humidity of the basement?

I did one 1920 basement with interior perimeter drain and put dimple board against the inside of the foundation wall leading down under the slab and sealed the top to the foundation wall allowing the moisture to come out of the wall and drain down under the slab.  I did also separate the exterior rain drain to pickup the majority of the liquid water that could get to the foundation wall.  FHB had an article about an old structure that had a creek running through the basement that they water proofed around.

I've done it the other way on a 1920 house, dig the entire perimeter of the house, parge, tar and dimpleboard and install exterior perimeter drain, add separated rain drains.  It is a lot of work.